# My Hammer JS will not register my tap handler until I have used the pan function

Tags: javascript, cordova, hammer.js

I normally find all my answers here but I haven't seen this one yet.

So I have two hammer js event listeners, pan and tap.

Pan works perfectly all the time, however, the tap does not appear to be picked up by the event listener until the pan event handler has been called at least once, then it works perfectly.

I am coding an IOS app using Cordova.

I apologise if this has been asked already! (First question on here)

Do you guys have any suggestions or solutions?

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('screenWidth');
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
mc.add( new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 1 }) );
mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({direction:Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL, 
threshold:80, pointers: 0}));


mc.on("panend", function(ev) {
if(ev.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT)
{ 
  //alert("Swipe right.");
}
else if (ev.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT)
{
  //alert("Swipe left.");
}

mc.on("doubletap", function(e){

  var tapX = e.center.x;
  var tapY = e.center.y;
  console.log(tapX + " + " + tapY);

  e.gesture.srcEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer - I moved the tap event handler before the pan event handler and now everything works perfectly.